# Hide Gridview Until Datatable Loads

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatables

Using Gridview and Datatables, since the Gridview loads faster than the datatable, I want to hide it until the datatable finishes loading, find here a [Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4UOa.gif) of what happens (not mine [Original Post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/52707/asp-net-gridview-as-datatable-loading-data-twice)).

I have tried to change the display attribute to "none" and set it "run-in" after the datatable is ready but i get this result [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnmtr.png) (please see code bellow)
Have also tried to set Gridview.hide() and after load Gridview.show() but it loads the gridview then hides it and then shows it again.

HTML

```
<div class="spinner-border text-primary" style="display:block" id="spinner" runat="server" role="status">
<span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewParts" style="display:none" OnRowDataBound="GridViewQuotes_RowDataBound"
runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePart" >
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var table = $('#<%= GridViewParts.ClientID %>').DataTable(
   "fnDrawCallback": function () {
   // Hide the Loading Spinner...
   $('#<%= spinner.ClientID %>').hide();
   $('#<%= GridViewParts.ClientID %>').style.display ='run-in';
}
```

I have done some research and the posts on the topic never have a final answer.

Comment: If you set visible = false on the server side, the GridView markup won't even appear in the resulting HTML. You'll need to use an attribute that still renders the markup,  but makes it invisible. Look into the CSS Display property.

Comment: I tried setting the display property to "none" and than chaging it to "run-in", but the table won't load the values, only the external fields. [link] (https://imgur.com/a/wugyTWU)

Comment: What you have shown in your question is clearly wrong. Fix it according to how I told you. If you still have an issue, then update your [mcve].

Comment: Ok i will, thank you.

Comment: I have edited the question with the fix u suggested, please take a look, have also added a new image.

Comment: Now what do you mean by "the table won't load the values, only the external fields"? What values? What external fields?

Comment: I will be more clear, here is a picture of what i get after trying to use the display property (https://ibb.co/whX5Xdh), and this is what was supposed to show (https://ibb.co/MsCNtnQ).

Comment: I can't see that. My company's firewall blocks the image hosting there. You need to clearly describe here what behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Ok sure, the table itself (columns, rows and cells) won't load, it only loads the search bar, paging (where it says page 1, 2,3 etc) and the show entries (where u select how many entries per time u want to display) all that is rendered in the javascript portion.

Comment: Hmm. I wouldn't use a GridView here. GridView are like super special tables.....kind of like DataTables are super special tables....you're going to run into issues if you try to combine both. Instead, have you considered using a Table control? Or even a Repeater, and general the appropriate HTML markup yourself? Or have the JavaScript retrieve the table content from the server side rather than embedding all the table markup on the page at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so we want to display the spinner, and then load the table.

Well, I hit some rather large tables, and response times are WELL under one second. I don't see how (or why) one would be loading up a gridview with more then say 100 records. After that amount, then your going to torture and abuse your users with such a long list to scroll though. So not at all clear why load times are not well UNDER 1 second anyway.

Next up, if the grid really is to have a lot of records, then you REALLY need to introduce a data pager. This again will say only pull 30-40 records at a time, and once again, that means very little delay.

However, having said all the above? Well, we can set things up this way:

When we display the page, we ALSO display the spinner. We THEN have the client side browser trigger the button to load up and display the grid.

So, lets drop the spinner on the page - a button, and a gridview.

The button when clicked is what will display our grid - we will HIDE THIS BUTTON and have the browser automatic click on this button for us.

Since the web page and code behind runs all at once, then we can't write code behind to show the spinner, load the grid, and hide the spinner. We can't do this, since all 3 operations will run ONE time in code behind. And when code behind runs, the web page is sitting up on the server. ONLY WHEN the code behind is done then is the page sent to the client side, and the contents are then displayed.

So, we have to do the following:

Let the page load, code behind runs, and THEN it is sent down tot he client side. At this point the page will display the spinner or whatever.

Then the browser side (client side) now has to trigger the grid view load. As noted, we just use a regular standard button we drop on the form.

So, we have this markup:

```
        <div id="MySpinner" runat="server">
            <img src="Content/wait2.gif" />
        </div>

        <asp:Button ID="cmdLoadGrid" runat="server" Text="Button" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="display:normal" />

        <div id="MyGrid" runat="server">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
        </div>

        <script>
            function LoadMyGrid() {
                mybtn = document.getElementById("cmdLoadGrid")
                mybtn.click()
            }
        </script>
```

So it looks like this:

[image]

Ok, so now lets double click on teh button, we jumped to code behind.

We have this:

```
Protected Sub cmdLoadGrid_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdLoadGrid.Click

    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City from tblHotels"

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using

    ' hide the spinner
    MySpinner.Style("Display") = "none"
    MyGrid.Style("Display") = "normal"

End Sub
```

Ok, now lets hide the button in the mark up.

Eg now this:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdLoadGrid" runat="server" Text="Button" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="display:none" />
```

Ok, now in our first page load, we set the page to run/trigger our above js routine that clicks our button to run the code behind to load up the grid.

But, since this button click occurs AFTER the page has been sent client side and rendered, then the user will see the spinner while the grid loads.

The on-load event is thus this:

```
    If IsPostBack = False Then
        ' first page load - set our client side function
        ' LoadMyGrid() to run

        Dim strMyJava = "LoadMyGrid()"
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "My Load script", strMyJava, True)

    End If
```

And there we have it.

The results look like this:

[image]

As noted, since the grid loads so fast, then the spinner does not stay in view very long. But, if the grid did take a few seconds, then the spinner would display for a few seconds.

Comment: Hi Albert, thank you very much for the complete reply. I have made the changes as described and your explanations was super clear, but i don't think it solved the problem. I'm having trouble with the Datatable load, which only happens after the Gridview Load. I recorded what is happening after i tried your solution [Gif](https://gifyu.com/image/DVzS). The spinner is working , but it still falls into the same problem in which the gridview loads, then the datatables loads on top of it. I need a way to hide this gridview, load the JS code for the datatable and then present the final table only.

Comment: My posted code does exaclty that. The page will load FIRST - the spinner will be displayed. Now the js code clicks the button to load the grid. Yes, this should work just fine. So when the page loads, the code to run that loads the gird has not started. You HAVE to get the page loaded and displayed on the client browser, and THEN inject the script that WHICH runs AFTER the page loads. I used a hidden asp.net button since it makes the code oh so simple. Try the sample markup as posted - it works fine. You code on page load MUST NOT attempt to load the grid - only that hidden button when clicked

Comment: As a test just drop a button on the page. Have the page load with the spinner displayed. the spinner will display forever. Now click on your button to load the grid and hide the spinner. Spinner display until the grid loads, and then the grid will display. So get this working WITHOUT the js code. Don't hide the button on the form that loads the grid. Get this ALL working without any js (skip that part for testing). Get button working when you click on that button it loads the grid. Once you have that working then add the script inject code, and use style="display:none" to hide that button.

Comment: I looked at your gif. I don't see where that button on the form is clicked to load the grid. Your grid is being loaded by code behind BEFORE the page is rendered. Again: remove the js code. Un-hide the hidden button that you MUST click on to display the grid. Get this working. So page displays. On that page you have a button, and YOU MUST click that button to load the grid. ONLY AFTER you get this working, then can ou introduce js code and introduce the register script. But DO NOT try the script and register script UNTILL SUCH TIME you have the form load, and then you HAVE to click on button